# How to make dd($request->hasFile('photo')); return TRUE and upload image in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, image, image-uploading

I want to upload image but my image can't upload and i check with `dd($request->hasFile('supply_photo'));` i get return FALSE and i check again with `dd($request->all())` i get

```
"_token" => "ETFJYrRIe6MWqk0LAwXXfBBIHEldHBP4bDeICbpi" 
"item" => "1" 
"tgl_date" => "2019-07-11" 
"use_date" => "2019-07-12" 
"details" => "1" 
"photo" => "A.jpg" ]
```

I have controller

```
if($request->hasFile('photo') == true){
                $photo = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                    'photo' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg',
                ]);

    if($photo->fails()){
                return redirect()->back()->with('warning', 'Image size should be 2MB or less');
        }            
        $image = $request->file('photo');
        $image_name = rand().'.'. $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $destination_path = public_path('/item');
        $image->move($destination_path, $image_name);
    }
        $data->item = $request->item;
        $data->details = $request->details;
        $data->tgl_date = $request->tgl_date;
        //$leave->leave_days = $request->days;
        $data->use_date = $request->use_date;
        $data->id = $id;
        $data->photo = $image_name;
        $data->save();
```

And my View

```
 <label for="photo">Photo</label>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="photo">
```

Comment: You are getting a string in your request (filename) instead of UploadedFile instance. You must check your view for errors. Where is closing form tag? Can you post more data from your view?

Answer (score -1):

In laravel application must be using laravel storage try to visit https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem

in upload file here is the sample code

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
Storage::put('file.jpg', $contents);
```